# How to find separate cpu1 and cpu2 usage in snmpwalk?

Tags: centos, snmp, net-snmp

I want to get the usage of `cpu1` and `cpu2` usage separately using `snmpwalk`.

Mine is dual core cpu. Can anybody know what is the exact OID for the cpu1 and cpu2 usage?

I am using centos operating system. Thank you

Comment: I don't think you can get per CPU usage report from SNMP, http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Net-snmp_5.3_CPU_collections You might review CentOS's latest documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The OID HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrProcessorLoad (.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2) shows the CPU percentage per processor (averaged over the last minute).  However, the *index* of that OID is HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrDeviceIndex (.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.1), so you won't get something convenient like ".1" for the first processor and ".2" for the second one.  Instead, you'll probably get something like this:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -cpublic localhost HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrProcessorLoad
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrProcessorLoad.196608 = INTEGER: 15
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrProcessorLoad.196609 = INTEGER: 3
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrProcessorLoad.196610 = INTEGER: 4
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrProcessorLoad.196611 = INTEGER: 3
```

What matters is that each entry represents a different processor (or core, or whatever).  Here, you can see that this box has four such processors.

To get something a little bit more descriptive for the kind of processor, you can check HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrDeviceDescr (.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.3).  For example:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -cpublic localhost HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrDeviceDescr
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrDeviceDescr.196608 = STRING: AuthenticAMD: AMD Phenom(tm) 9550 Quad-Core Processor
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrDeviceDescr.196609 = STRING: AuthenticAMD: AMD Phenom(tm) 9550 Quad-Core Processor
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrDeviceDescr.196610 = STRING: AuthenticAMD: AMD Phenom(tm) 9550 Quad-Core Processor
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrDeviceDescr.196611 = STRING: AuthenticAMD: AMD Phenom(tm) 9550 Quad-Core Processor
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrDeviceDescr.262145 = STRING: network interface lo
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrDeviceDescr.262146 = STRING: network interface eth1
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrDeviceDescr.786432 = STRING: Guessing that there's a floating point co-processor
```

Here, you can see that there are more things indexed by HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrDeviceIndex than just the processors.  For example, the two network interfaces ("lo" and "eth1") are listed.  Just be sure to ask for the indexes that match those of your processors.